# Where Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu used to originally reside?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

Lord Shiva is a resident of mountain Kailaasa which is in the Himalaya i.e. in-laws place. Lord Vishnu is resident of Kshirsagar i.e. also a in-laws place. So my question is - Where did Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu reside originally?

Comment: Lord Shiva doesnt have any loka. because he is the unmanifest Parabrahman. Shri Maha Vishnu's home is Vaikunatha as described Vaishnavaism texts!

Comment: According to Yaska, the vedic etymologist, Vishnu is derived from the root word Vish, which means "to pervade". Vishnu pervades everything from inside and outside.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti There is Kailasa. That's where he resides. He is called Kailasapati. (If you mean Rudra !=  etc., comments are not the place to give such hidden yet detailed meaning. Even Vishnu is called the Parabrahman and lies everywhere in the universe. This goes both ways.) Hence it is better not to comment giving confusing replies especially to new users. Please use answer section. It could be misleading if there are upvotes.